# Forged signature in DHL Invoice

Tags: united-kingdom, india, customs-law, forgery

My sister in India sent her dysfunctional iphone to me in the UK through DHL. She signed some paperwork and was charged Rs. 4300 for the transfer. She did not quote a value for the product nor did she sign an invoice.

To receive the product, DHL asked me to pay a sum of £54 towards duty and VAT. I requested the customer retention team an invoice, and they sent me the paperwork signed by my sister in India.

We were shocked to see an invoice with a forged signature of my sister, quoting a price of £200 for the iPhone. The DHL has forged her signature for getting a higher amount of tax, while the iphone itself was worthless, as it was dysfunctional.

What legal recourse do I have? Can they be tried in the UK, as I have been wrongly made to pay £54? Or does this come under Indian jurisdiction? Is there an easy online way to protect my consumer rights?

Comment: Was DHL aware that the iPhone was not functional? It's entirely possible they did that because the phone wouldn't have gotten through UK customs without a listed value and thus they went with some default value for a smartphone, though signature forging is an issue, of course.

Comment: That an item is not working does not make its value zero. its value is the market price of the working item minus the repair cost. And even an unreparable item may be used in a renewal program, so making its value not zero. Otherwise, there would be a whole industry of damaging/reparing phones (for example, isolating the battery contacts) to avoid paying taxes. And of course, if it were just a paperweight you would not had it shipped from India to the UK.